# Vault for Kafka distributed connectors

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using a [JBoss based vault](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.2/html-single/how_to_configure_server_security/index#password_vault) to secure sensitive data such as the database credentials.

I use a Java based HTTP REST client to create distributed Kafka connectors but ended up with a security concern such that a request for the connector's "config" exposes the sensitive credentials in the response.

I referred this official [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-297%3A+Externalizing+Secrets+for+Connect+Configurations) but could not get much help in the context of JBoss vault.

Any pointers or references that directly addresses this specific problem is very much appreciated.

Any references to alternate open source (and free to use) Vault based solutions would also be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to write code that implements the ConfigProvider interface of the Connect API, mentioned there.

You can browse Kafka source code on Github to see the existing File one, but that KIP (which references Hashicorp Vault) and the source files are the only such documentation for now.

Connect doesn't use JBoss, either, so you'd have to find a way around that